# javascript calculator display text box

Tags: javascript

why my script will not work? i feel like may be issue is browser related. it will not work in chrome or IE.

my code is below. i have worked on it for a while i don't understand why it would not work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-  8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" >//src="calc.js">

      function displayVal(val){
        //document.getElementById("disp").value=val;
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('b').onclick(function(){
            $('display').value=val;
          });
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myDocument" id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="display" id="display" value=""/>
      <input type="button" name="buttons" value="1" />
      <input type="button" name="buttons" value="2" />
      <input type="button" name="buttons" value="3" /></br>
      <input type="button" name="buttons" value="+" />
      <input type="button" name="buttons" value="=" />
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is incomplete.

Comment: You are not adding jQuery.

Comment: ok. i made change. <br /> still wouldn't work.

Comment: Wow. You think that is the mistake? Boss, check out my answer.

Comment: I don't see where displayVal() is actually getting called.

Comment: Not only the above mistakes. There are a lot.

1. There's no `<b>` element to get it called.
2. All the `<input />`s have same name, I don't understand how that's helping as a "calculator".
3. There's no `click` event associated with the buttons.

Altogether, the HTML that you have provided is worth for nothing, just an image.

Comment: @authorx Kindly check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason, I could see is, of course, you are not adding a jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And finally you are calling this:

```
$('b').onclick(function() { ... });
```

There's no `<b>` element at all.

This is totally wrong:

```
$('display').value=val;
```

It should be:

```
$("#display").val(val);
```

Not only the above mistakes, but in addition to the above, there are a lot.

1. There's no `<b>` element to get it called.
2. All the `<input />`s have same name, I don't understand how that's helping as a "calculator".
3. There's no `click` event associated with the buttons.
4. You don't need the `displayVal()` function.
5. jQuery's `$.click` function, not `onclick`.

Altogether, the HTML that you have provided is worth for nothing, just an image. This would be a better alternate.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Calci</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
          var oldVal = 0;
          var op = "";
          // n - number
          // o - operation
          $('.n').click(function () {
            $('#display').val($('#display').val() + $(this).val());
          });
          $(".o").click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "+") {
              if (op == "+")
                oldVal = parseInt(oldVal) + parseInt($('#display').val());
              else
                oldVal = parseInt($('#display').val());
              $('#display').val("");
              op = "+";
            } else {
              if (op == "+")
                oldVal = parseInt(oldVal) + parseInt($('#display').val());
              else
                oldVal = parseInt($('#display').val());
              $('#display').val(oldVal);
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myDocument" id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="display" id="display" value="" /><br />
      <input type="button" class="n" value="1" />
      <input type="button" class="n" value="2" />
      <input type="button" class="n" value="3" /><br />
      <input type="button" class="o" value="+" />
      <input type="button" class="o" value="=" />
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  var oldVal = 0;
  var op = "";
  // n - number
  // o - operation
  $('.n').click(function () {
    $('#display').val($('#display').val() + $(this).val());
  });
  $(".o").click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "+") {
      if (op == "+")
        oldVal = parseInt(oldVal) + parseInt($('#display').val());
      else
        oldVal = parseInt($('#display').val());
      $('#display').val("");
      op = "+";
    } else {
      if (op == "+")
        oldVal = parseInt(oldVal) + parseInt($('#display').val());
      else
        oldVal = parseInt($('#display').val());
      $('#display').val(oldVal);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myDocument" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="display" id="display" value="" /><br />
  <input type="button" class="n" value="1" />
  <input type="button" class="n" value="2" />
  <input type="button" class="n" value="3" /><br />
  <input type="button" class="o" value="+" />
  <input type="button" class="o" value="=" />
</form>
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/popavosezi**

Comment: i made some changes insted jQuery i am using javascript and now my script is

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >//src="calc.js">

Comment: function displayVal(val){
      document.getElementById("display").value=val;}

Comment: and then i am calling this function

Comment: <input type="button" name="buttons" value="1" onlclick="displayVal(1);"/>

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var x = '';
    $('[name="buttons"]').click(function() {
      //console.log($('[name="buttons"]').val());
      x += $(this).val();
      $("#display").val(x);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="display" id="display" value="" />
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="1" />
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="2" />
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="3" />
    </br>
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="+" />
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="=" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ya,it dosen't do the calculation